# How can I determine the custom forms that are attached to a project using the API

Tags: workfront-api

If I use Workfront from a browser and I create a new project, I am able to click on "Custom Forms" and I see a list of custom forms I can use with this newly created project. How can I use the workfront-api to list the custom forms that are available or being used by a particular project?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer:

https://yourdomain.com/attask/api-internal/project/{Your Project ID}?fields=objectCategories:category:name